# Xamarin forms same image has different size depending the way it's loaded

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms

I'm loading a list of album covers using a collection view

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                         Margin="8"
                         xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True">
                <Image Source="{Binding Url}"
                       BackgroundColor="Black" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Depending of the URL that I bind the image loaded is different, I mean if I load the image from internet URL, the image is loaded full size, but if a load from an internal storage URL the image is loaded small.
Why this is happening if the image is the same?

I have tried all the aspects, but does not work, because the height of the image is currently settled.

Using `https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3`

[image]

But using `/data/user/0/com.company.packagename/files/.local/share/unnamed.png`

[image: Using local image]

Comment: try specifying as Aspect on the Image.  I'd guess that when loading from disk the size of the image can be calculated when the layout cycle occurs, where loading remotely requires the layout to occur before the image data is available

Comment: Hi @Jason I have tried all the aspects, but does not work, because the height of the image is currently settled. That only stretch the image

Comment: I don't know why, but it looks like it is using default image size (not based on your image), and then failing to update it. 1) Try CollectionView ItemSizingStrategy=MeasureAllItems. 2) Remove the outer `<StackLayout>` of ItemTemplate. Nested layouts sometimes have layout issues. 3) Worst case, might have to set HeightRequest on `<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"`. (Assuming you've removed the outer one.)

Comment: Hi @ToolmakerSteve but none of your suggestions works. Currently I define the HeightRequest and I'll to bind it with a property in the ViewModel and that property will be settled depending of the screen phone dimentions... 
It's not very clean, but I think will work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend directly downloading the image to `Resources->drawable` Folder and then consume it like below. It works well on my side.

```
   <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyListProperty}"> 

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                 Span="2">
            </GridItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout 
                       Orientation="Vertical"
                       Margin="8">

                        <Image Source="{Binding Url}"
                           BackgroundColor="Black"/>

                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```